# Gap in tcolorbox after title

Tags: tcolorbox

I want this type of output. [image]

I wrote the following code.

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter]{project}{Project}{
lower separated=true,
colback=white!90!blue,
colframe=white,
colbacktitle=white!80!blue,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
boxed title style={colframe=white!80!blue},
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-3.5mm},
 }{def}
\begin{document}
\begin{project}{}
  Project
\end{project}
\end{document}
```

The output that I got is [image]

I am not getting a gap after the title. Please help me with this and also the boxed are not round enough.

Comment: \begin{project}{} 
\vskip 1cm
  Project
\end{project}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of the `top` option you can define the distance between the text and the frame:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter]{project}{Project}{
lower separated=true,
colback=white!90!blue,
colframe=white,
colbacktitle=white!80!blue,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
top=5mm, %<------------ Added
boxed title style={colframe=white!80!blue},
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-3.5mm},
 }{def}


\begin{document}
\begin{project}{}{}
  with top=5mm
\end{project}
\end{document}
```

More information on the various spacing options can be found in section "4.7.4  Spacing" (page 39) of the [`tcolorbox` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

For "rounder" edges, you can use the `arc` option as in the following exaggerated example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter]{project}{Project}{
lower separated=true,
colback=white!90!blue,
colframe=white!90!blue,
colbacktitle=white!80!blue,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
top=5mm,
boxed title style={colframe=white!80!blue},
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-3.5mm},
arc=5mm % <--------------------- Added
}{def}



\begin{document}

\begin{project}{}{}
  with top=5mm and arch=5 mm
\end{project}

\end{document}
```

More information on how to control the space of box corners can be found in section "4.7.3  Arcs" (page 36)  of the [`tcolorbox` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

Comment: What about the round boxes?

Comment: @XYZABC, if you need information regarding the `tcolorbox` options please have a look at the (very) [comprehensive documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)

Comment: @XYZABC: Sorry, but I don't understand what exactly your comment refers to. Could you please add a bit more explanation?

Comment: I want the box would be in more round like corners should be more round.

Comment: @XYZABC: The shape of the corners can be changed with the `arc` option. I have edited my answer to also include an example on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5):

When you use an `attached title` you should consider that the title box is independent of the contents box, therefore, if you want to place part of the title box below the border of the text box, the contents should be also moved.

In this case you can use `yshift*` option (page 160 in v4.20 documentation) which fixes the vertical title displacement but also a similar movement for the text into main box. The needed shift can be automatically computed using `\tcboxedtitleheight` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter]{project}{Project}{
lower separated=true,
colback=white!90!blue,
colframe=white,
colbacktitle=white!80!blue,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
boxed title style={colframe=white!80!blue},
attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2, xshift=.5cm},
}{def}

\begin{document}
\begin{project}{Project's title}{Label}
\lipsum[1]
\end{project}

As can be seen in Projetc~\ref{def:Label} \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter]{project}{Project}{
lower separated=true,
colback=white!90!blue,
colframe=white!90!blue,
colbacktitle=white!80!blue,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
boxed title style={colframe=white!80!blue},
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-3.5mm},
}{def}

\begin{documnt}

\begin{project}{}{}
  \vskip 1cm 
  Bla bla 
\end{project}

\end{document}
```

The above will give you proper space.[image]

Comment: Could you please make your example code compilable? When I try your suggestion, I recieve the following error message: `Missing \endcsname inserted.`

Comment: Please do not add incomplete code. Also, if you run this code using the information provided by the OP, it actually misses one `{}` after the `\begin{project}{}` which swallows the first character after that (or worse)

Comment: @leandriis Sorry, I updated my answer.

Comment: @leandriis Could you please let me know if you are getting the error message?

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad: Now the error message is gone. However, there is a type on `\begin{document}`. Also, I get a different ouptu. The vertical space is a lot larger compared to your screenshot.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad: You might also want to add a comment that this solution is only local. So if one needs several of these boxes, the `\vskip` would have to be applied to each and every box.

Comment: But, I guess, in your answer also one has to write with top=5mm every time. If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad: Actually in my answer, I added the `top=5mm` option to `\newtcbtheorem` so this will automatically apply to  all boxes of the `project` type. (` with top=5mm` in `\begin{project}{}{}
  with top=5mm
\end{project}` is just some filler text.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was not knowing that.